# Волновой алгоритм

Tags: алгоритм

Подскажите пожалуйста временную сложность волнового алгоритма поиска кратчайшего пути между двумя точками в таблице?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первые же несколько  ссылок, по запросу

```
волновой алгоритм вычислительная сложность
```

в гугле, утверждают, что квадратичная (что соответствует интуитивной оценке).